# React change text on button click in a function

Tags: reactjs, state

Considering this React function:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import HomeScreen from  './Screens/HomeScreen'
import './App.css';
import currentStrings from './utils/currentlang'

function App() {
  const currentlang = currentStrings;
  const switchLanguage = () =>{
    console.log("switching...");
    currentlang.switchLang();
  } 
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
       <div className="grid-container">
        <header className="header">
          <div className="brand">
            <Link to="/" >
               
            </Link>
          </div>
          <div className="header-side">
            {currentlang.getCurrent.subtitle}
          </div>
          <div className="header-right">
            <button  onClick={switchLanguage}> {currentlang.getCurrent.traduction} </button>
          </div>
          <div>

          </div>
        </header>
        <main className="main">
          <div className="content">
            <Route path="/" exact={true} component={HomeScreen} />
          </div>

        </main>
        <footer className="footer">
          &#169; 2020 
         </footer>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
   
  );
}

export default App;
```

i want to switch the language when i click on the button, the function itself changes a variable that contains the list of html text. However, all the research has given me solutions by using classes to change the state of my page, but my project is functional and doesn't work in my context.

Comment: In order to see a change in the component, the `currentStrings` has go come as a prop to your app functional component `function App(props)` or a hook like this : `const [currentStrings, setCurrentStrings] = React.useState(initValue)`

Comment: i have several questions about it. How can i pass to <App> the parameter in index.js?, i tried to use <App currentStrings=currentStrings> and react says that the methods of the object are undefined. And what initialValue should i put in useState, the object itself?

Comment: Yes, the initial value is the object itself.

Comment: And if you do the other way `<App currentStrings=currentStrings>` , the `currentStrings` has to be in a useState hook or in the state of the class component in which you call the App component